# How to Update Table based on Array Keys as column names? PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

**This is different from Insert based on Keys**

I would like to know how to use the array_keys of an array as column names for an update query. The object is that I have a form with all the data a user can update like Gender, Country, Nationality, etc. But say the user only wants to update their Country, therefor array_filter filters the array of all NULL/Empty values. Then I want the keys as names of Columns to update; however, I'd like to know how to bind them together.

Perhaps so they go together like so:

```
"UPDATE Users SET" . $Columns . "WHERE ID = 5";
```

I want Columns to be in the format. "Nation = US, Gender = Male" etc.

My current code:

```
<?php
class Update {    
    private $UpdateColumn;
    private $UpdatedData;
    private $ID;

    protected $Connect;
    protected $Data;

    public function __construct($UpdateColumn, $ID) {
        try {
            $this->Connect = new pdo(****); //Hidden for privacy test server
            $this->Connect->setAttribute(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
                PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            );   
        } catch(PDOException $ex) {
            die(json_encode([
                'outcome' => false,
                'message' => 'Unable to connect'
            ]));
        }

        $this->UpdateColumn = $UpdateColumn;
        $this->ID = $ID;
    }

    public function bindData() {
        $this->Data = [
            $this->UpdateColumn,
            $this->ID
        ];

        return $this->Data;
    }

    public function checkForErrors(){

        foreach($this->Data as $Data){
            $Error = false;

            if(empty($Data)){
                $Error = true;
            }

            if(isNum($Data[1])){
                $Error = true;
            }
        }

        return $Error;    
    }

    public function Update() {
        $Query = $this->Connect->prepare(
            "UPDATE Users SET". $this->Data[0] . "WHERE ID = :ID"
        );
        $Query->bindValue(":ID", $this->Data[1]);
        $Query->execute();
    }

    public function Redirect(){
        return header("Location: /Profile?ID=$this->Data[1]");
    }
}
```

Place to use the code.

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once("Scripts/PHP/Class/Update.class.php");

$DataUpdate = array_filter($_POST);
$Columns = array_keys($DataUpdate);

$ColumnsToUpdate = implode($Columns, ", ");
//I want to have ColumnsToUpdate look like: Gender = Male, Age = 67, format
//$Update = new Update($ColumnsToUpdate, $DataUpdate, $_SESSION['ID']);

?>
```

**In my case then, I will need an array delimiter which I could use to go through each array_key with it's counterpart data**

```
$Array = array(
    "Age" => 9,
    "Gender" => "Boy",
    "Country" => "",
);

$Array = array_filter($Array);
$Columns = array_keys($Array);

$ColumnToSend = "";

foreach($Array as $Arr => $Key){
    $ColumnToSend .= $Arr ."=". $Key . ",";
}

echo($ColumnToSend);
```

That produces the desired format, but would it work if it was put into a query?

Comment: Any reason you can't use a simple `foreach()` loop to build a query string? You'll need to be *very* careful to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: I am very aware of injection.

Comment: @miken32 I used a foreach, which produced desired format, but if inserted into query, would it execute properly?

Comment: Try it and see. Make sure you're quoting things properly. I see zero code in there to mitigate SQL injection.

Comment: I know I didn't include my sanitization function.

Comment: Also since I am not binding anything with :placeholders will that increase my chance of injection?

Comment: Yes. You can still use placeholders for the value, but not the column name, which is where the danger lies in doing this sort of query. I'd stick with placeholders for values and very aggressively sanitize column names; or, better yet, match them against a whitelist.

Comment: I am using prepared statements, however. @miken32

Comment: Yes, by aggressively sanitize them; how so? Also how would one continue to use placeholders for values, if I am using the method that I am? Is it even a viable solution with a foreach, in the means I am going about?

Comment: `preg_replace('/[^0-9a-z_]/', '', $column_name);` Whitelist against known column names would be better though.

Comment: Ok thanks, had you written this as an answer, I'd award you the green "Answer Checkmark"! I'll get back to you with my results.

Comment: I am implementing a whitelist in the checkForErrors code! @miken32

Comment: Unless you are dealing with a really big bunch of data, once the user send new data, just delete all related data from your destiny table and insert everything all over again.

Comment: Please elaborate, what would this accomplish? @FlávioFilho

Comment: why would I waste queries on… Insert, delete, insert again?

Comment: As I understand, you are asking on how to update the data of a table, from the users entering. So I think the approach is not efficient. I think the best way is not to update, but delete and reinsert everything. That's what I used to do in my projects.

Comment: Course it works, as I said before, for a not big amount of data. If you are dealing with hundred of thousand records, it would be much expensive in terms of resources.

Comment: No that's not what I'm trying to accomplish, but thanks for the thought, and even if it was this would not be a viable option. @FlávioFilho